# How to print out all the solutions in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print out the list containing all the solutions to a problem, but Prolog is giving me only part of the solutions and is cutting off in the middle like this:

`[[something-something], [something-something], [something-something], [...-...], [...][...].`

How do I get Prolog to print all the solutions?

Answer (score 7):

I use maplist/2

```
?- numlist(1,10,L),maplist(writeln,L).
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

If you are running SWI-Prolog, you can instruct it to avoid ellipsis

```
?- [user].
|: no_ellipsis :-
|:     current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, V),
|:     select(max_depth(_), V, U),
|:     set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, U).
|: end_of_file.
|: % user://3 compiled 0,05 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- no_ellipsis.
true .

?- numlist(1,20,L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20].
```

such rule could be placed in startup file, ( ~/.plrc on Unix )

Or you could use a write predicate

```
?- numlist(1,20,L),format('~w',[L]).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to write it out. The default interactive pretty printer in SWI-Prolog does this to avoid swamping you with output. So, if right now you're doing:

```
?- foo(X).
X = [[something-something], [something-something], [something-something], [...-...], [...][...].
```

Instead do this:

```
?- foo(X), write(X), nl.
... the complete output ...
X = [[something-something], [something-something], [something-something], [...-...], [...][...].
```

For instance:

```
?- length(X, 10), write(X), nl.
[_G1607,_G1610,_G1613,_G1616,_G1619,_G1622,_G1625,_G1628,_G1631,_G1634]
X = [_G1607, _G1610, _G1613, _G1616, _G1619, _G1622, _G1625, _G1628, _G1631|...].
```